# Python loop doesn't return complex numbers (instead, returns nan)

Tags: python, loops, complex-numbers

I've created a function that returns the roots of a 4th degree polynomial (I'm not using a ready library function for various reasons). The function returns up to 4 arguments, some can be real and some can be complex. When using the function outside of a loop it works exactly as expected. However, looping it causes the complex arguments to be returned as 'nan'.

I also tried putting the function code directly inside the loop, but I still got 'nan'.

Here is the function and loop. Only complex numbers should be returned when we set the parameters to `mu = 0.5` and `x >= -0.22 & x <= 0.22`

```py
def poly4(a, b, c, d, e):
    disc_0 = c**2 - 3*b*d + 12*a*e
    disc_1 = 2*c**3 - 9*b*c*d + 27*(b**2)*e + 27*a*d**2 - 72*a*c*e
    p = (8*a*c - 3*b**2) / (8*a**2)
    q = (b**3 - 4*a*b*c + 8*(a**2)*d) / (8*a**3)
    Q = ((disc_1 + (disc_1**2 - 4*disc_0**3)**0.5) / 2)**(1/3)
    S = 0.5 * (-(2/3)*p + (3*a)**(-1) * (Q + disc_0 / Q))**0.5

    x1 = -b/(4*a) - S + 0.5 * (-4*S**2 - 2*p + q/S)**0.5
    x2 = -b/(4*a) - S - 0.5 * (-4*S**2 - 2*p + q/S)**0.5
    x3 = -b/(4*a) + S + 0.5 * (-4*S**2 - 2*p - q/S)**0.5
    x4 = -b/(4*a) + S - 0.5 * (-4*S**2 - 2*p - q/S)**0.5
    return x1, x2, x3, x4
```

```py
x = 0.1
mu = 0.5

a = 1
b = -2*x
c = x**2+mu**2-1
d = 2*x
e = -x**2

print(poly4(a, b, c, d, e))
```

```py
x_vec = np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2, 5)
mu = 0.5

for i in x_vec:
    x = i
    a = 1
    b = -2*x
    c = x**2+mu**2-1
    d = 2*x
    e = -x**2
    result = poly4(a, b, c, d, e)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Since you're not actually *using* NumPy for this, I replaced your `linspace` call with the equivalent tuple, `(-0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2)`.  The program ran just fine.

Comment: The problem is I actually need 400 data points from -1 to 1, and creating them manually isn't a great idea. Converting a ```linspace``` to tuple or list didn't solve the problem

Comment: I agree with @prune that your function works fine when not using numpy. The error seems to be coming from this `Q = ((disc_1 + (disc_1**2 - 4*disc_0**3)**0.5) / 2)**(1/3)`. Specifically, `(disc_1**2 - 4*disc_0**3)**0.5)`. When you use linspace the datatype is np.float64 and it seems like this could be a floating point error. When -0.2 is passed the value returned from  `(disc_1**2 - 4*disc_0**3)**0.5)` is of the order e-17, but when linspace is used and the dtpye is np.float64 this section returns nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside your `for i in x_vec:` loop, `i` is a NumPy (rank-0) array -- a scalar.
These have a specific type (likely `numpy.float64`) that will not be automatically cast to a complex-capable type (like e.g. `numpy.complex128`), contrarily to what happens with Python `float`s being silently casted to `complex` as needed.

A simple fix would just be to replace `x = i` with `x = i.astype(complex)` or other similar casting (e.g. `x_vec = np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2, 5).astype(complex)`), if you need `i` or `x_vec` to be a NumPy array.

Alternatively, you may want to convert `x_vec` to a Python `list` (e.g. `x_vec = np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2, 5).tolist()`) which will then ensure `i`/`x` to fall-back to Python automatic casting.

Comment: Thank you! ```x = i.astype(complex)``` worked like a charm. And thanks for the explanation